# efibootmanager -o changes are lost on reboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bootloader, boot-order

Trying to install ubuntu on a laptop. The "bios/uefi" has no uefi boot options & the windows boot manager just kicks in. The only "option" is "boot from hard disk". So we tried to use `efibootmgr` to put grub to boot first.

When we run an `efibootmgr -o xxxx,xxxx,xxxx` command it seems like the order gets fixed but on reboot the windows boot manager still has control, then when we re-opened the live usb & checked the boot order it remains unaffected.

What are other ways to change the efi boot order? Maybe by mounting the efi partition (`in mnt`) and doing what?

Comment: If you use the EFI menu (some function key at power-on) and select Ubuntu (or maybe HDD, then Ubuntu on the next menu), does it boot?  What make/model is the laptop?  Did your install replace the /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi with a copy of shimx64.efi or grubx64.efi (it was originally a copy of Windows' bootmgfw.efi)?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289527/uefi-firmware-resetting-bootorder

Answer (score 5):

This problem is often caused by a flaky EFI implementation, although sometimes it could be argued that it's an `efibootmgr` bug. Possible solutions include:

- **Upgrade your firmware** -- Check with the manufacturer to see if a firmware upgrade is available, and if so, apply it and try again. Note that the upgrade *might* wipe out the NVRAM pointer to GRUB (or whatever you're using to boot Ubuntu), so you should be prepared with an emergency boot plan (Boot Repair or rEFInd on a removable disk, for instance).
- **Use another tool** -- Sometimes another tool, such as a boot-order option in the computer's built-in setup utility, the `bcfg` command in an EFI shell, the `bcdedit` tool in Windows, or the third-party [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) tool in Windows, will get the job done when `efibootmgr` in Linux won't.
- **Return the computer for one that works** -- If you get this far and are still having problems, I recommend you return the computer for one that works. This is obviously only an option if the computer is new enough to be within the store's free-return period. If you go this route, be sure to write to the manufacturer to tell them why you've returned the computer; they won't be motivated to actually fix problems like this unless they feel some pain from returns and know why those returns occurred.
- **Hack the boot files** -- As a last resort, you can move/rename boot files so that the Windows boot loader (`EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` on the ESP) lives somewhere else and GRUB, Shim, rEFInd, or whatever you're using lives at that name instead, with any follow-on or configuration files it needs in the same directory. Boot Repair has an option to set this up semi-automatically on its Advanced area; and you can do it semi-automatically for rEFInd with the `mvrefind` command that comes with rEFInd, once rEFInd is installed.
- **Re-install in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode** -- OK, I lied; the above wasn't quite the *last* resort, but it's the last *semi-easy* solution. It's also often possible to re-install all your OSes in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, or at least to convert them to boot in this way. This task is likely to be *very* tedious, though, so it's not something I recommend unless you want to re-install for some other reason anyway.