# GRUB not appearing on startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I'm newbie to Ubuntu and I don't have much idea about UEFI. I've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my Dell Inspiron 5368 laptop. At first, everything was normal. Then I restarted and switched to windows by selecting "windows boot manager" from grub. Now grub is not appearing on startup.

I checked UEFI menu, and Ubuntu grub is not listed there (in boot sequence, only Windows boot appears) . My windows disk management is showing there are two efi partitions in my computer, where there should be one. Their sizes are almost equal ( 512 MB and 513 MB).

How can I get grub every time at startup ?? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the OSes in different drives, perhaps disconnecting the Windows drive while installing Ubuntu? That would have created a new EFI partition. You can now try to change the drive order (not the boot order), so it reads the boot entries from there and from where you can boot Grub.

Comment: @MichaelBay I basically followed this link ( [link](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html) ). First I shrunk the volume of my D:/ , then installed using a live usb following standard procedures, actually I don't know if it disconnects windows drive. 
And I'm not sure how to change drive order, can you help me with that ??

Comment: The linked procedure wouldn't have created another EFI partition. And I meant physical drives, not partitions. Also selecting the correct boot entry varies according to the hardware so no, I cannot help you with that.

Comment: It's possible, but not certain, that you're encountering the same problem described in [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887210/efibootmanager-o-changes-are-lost-on-reboot) I'm not marking this as a duplicate simply because Dells are usually better than this; but maybe yours is an exception to this rule....