# Error when booting Ubuntu after installing

Tags: boot, uefi

I want to install Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire E14 with the UEFI configuration. I ran the Ubuntu 17.04 installation successfully, but when I finished the installation process it asked me to restart. Up until this point everything goes as normal but when I restart my computer to start using it the UEFI configuration does not recognize the Ubuntu boot. It doesn't detect any bootable device. Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you remove the `boot` device before restarting the installation?

Comment: yes i did!! and thats when on the screen it said no bootable device... it doest give me any other option then to turn off the computer and turn it on again

Comment: An at UEFI settings > boot order can you see and select Ubuntu?

Comment: No it only shows me 3 usb optons, the internet option and the hard drive with the name... But when i had windows on it and ubuntu with lagacy configiration it never showed me any names just the options that i mention.

Comment: It sounds like you've got a buggy EFI. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887210/efibootmanager-o-changes-are-lost-on-reboot) for suggestions.