# Boot order changes automatically

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, gpt

I have a dual-boot laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows. My bootloader is GRUB, I have a GUID Partition Table (GPT) and my OS'es are installed using UEFI. The default boot order is:

1. Ubuntu, which boots on GRUB
2. Windows Boot Manager

By default, I boot on GRUB and then I choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

My problem is that when I have a USB Storage Media plugged in while booting or rebooting my laptop, the boot order changes and Windows Boot Manager goes first and boots directly to Windows.

System information (`dmidecode -q`):

```
BIOS Information
    Vendor: LENOVO
    Version: B0CN97WW
    Release Date: 01/08/2016
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 6144 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
        Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 1.97
    Firmware Revision: 1.97

System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 80E5
    Version: Lenovo G50-80
    Serial Number: XXXXXXXX
    UUID: 284A4633-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_80E5_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo G50-80
    Family: IDEAPAD

Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: Lenovo G50-80
    Version: 31900058 WIN
    Serial Number: XXXXXXXX
    Asset Tag: NO Asset Tag
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
    Type: Motherboard

Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Type: Notebook
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: Lenovo G50-80
    Serial Number: XXXXXXXX
    Asset Tag: NO Asset Tag
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0
    SKU Number: SKU Number

Processor Information
    Socket Designation: U3E1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Core i5
    Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
    ID: D4 06 03 00 FF FB EB BF
    Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 61, Stepping 4
    Flags:
        FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
        VME (Virtual mode extension)
        DE (Debugging extension)
        PSE (Page size extension)
        TSC (Time stamp counter)
        MSR (Model specific registers)
        PAE (Physical address extension)
        MCE (Machine check exception)
        CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
        APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
        SEP (Fast system call)
        MTRR (Memory type range registers)
        PGE (Page global enable)
        MCA (Machine check architecture)
        CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
        PAT (Page attribute table)
        PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
        CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
        DS (Debug store)
        ACPI (ACPI supported)
        MMX (MMX technology supported)
        FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
        SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
        SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
        SS (Self-snoop)
        HTT (Multi-threading)
        TM (Thermal monitor supported)
        PBE (Pending break enabled)
    Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz
    Voltage: 0.9 V
    External Clock: 100 MHz
    Max Speed: 2700 MHz
    Current Speed: 2200 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Socket BGA1168
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Core Count: 2
    Core Enabled: 2
    Thread Count: 4
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable
        Multi-Core
        Hardware Thread
        Execute Protection
        Enhanced Virtualization
        Power/Performance Control

Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 32 kB
    Maximum Size: 32 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Parity
    System Type: Data
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 32 kB
    Maximum Size: 32 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Parity
    System Type: Instruction
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 256 kB
    Maximum Size: 256 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 8-way Set-associative

Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L3 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
    Operational Mode: Write Back
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 3072 kB
    Maximum Size: 3072 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Synchronous
    Installed SRAM Type: Synchronous
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 12-way Set-associative

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Keyboard
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Keyboard Port

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Mouse
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Mouse Port

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: TV OUT
    External Connector Type: Mini DIN
    Port Type: Video Port

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: CRT
    External Connector Type: DB-15 female
    Port Type: Video Port

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: COM 1
    External Connector Type: DB-9 male
    Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J3A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J5A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J5A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J5A2
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J5A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Network
    External Connector Type: RJ-45
    Port Type: Network Port

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9G2
    Internal Connector Type: On Board Floppy
    External Reference Designator: OnBoard Floppy Type
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J7J1
    Internal Connector Type: On Board IDE
    External Reference Designator: OnBoard Primary IDE
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J30
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Microphone In
    External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
    Port Type: Audio Port

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J30
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Line In
    External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
    Port Type: Audio Port

Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J30
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Speaker Out
    External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
    Port Type: Audio Port

System Slot Information
    Designation: J6C1
    Type: x1 PCI Express x1
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 1
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.0

System Slot Information
    Designation: J6D2
    Type: x1 PCI Express x1
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 2
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.1

System Slot Information
    Designation: J7C1
    Type: x1 PCI Express x1
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Other
    ID: 3
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.2

System Slot Information
    Designation: J7D1
    Type: x1 PCI Express x1
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Other
    ID: 4
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.3

System Slot Information
    Designation: J8C1
    Type: x4 PCI Express x4
    Current Usage: Available
    Length: Other
    ID: 5
    Characteristics:
        PME signal is supported
        Hot-plug devices are supported
    Bus Address: 0000:00:1c.4

OEM Strings
    String 1: OemString1
    String 2: OemString2
    String 3: OemString3

System Configuration Options
    Option 1: ConfigOptions1
    Option 2: ConfigOptions2
    Option 3: ConfigOptions3

BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 8
        en|US|iso8859-1,0
        fr|CA|iso8859-1,0
        zh|TW|unicode,0
        ja|JP|unicode,0
        it|IT|iso8859-1,0
        es|ES|iso8859-1,0
        de|DE|iso8859-1,0
        pt|PT|iso8859-1,0
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1,0

Group Associations
    Name: Firmware Version Info
    Items: 6
        0x003B (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x003A (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x0039 (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x0038 (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x0037 (<OUT OF SPEC>)
        0x0036 (<OUT OF SPEC>)

Group Associations
    Name: Intel(R) Silicon View Technology
    Items: 1
        0x0041 (<OUT OF SPEC>)

System Event Log
    Area Length: 0 bytes
    Header Start Offset: 0x0000
    Header Length: 8192 bytes
    Data Start Offset: 0x2000
    Access Method: General-purpose non-volatile data functions
    Access Address: 0x0000
    Status: Valid, Not Full
    Change Token: 0x12345678
    Header Format: OEM-specific
    Supported Log Type Descriptors: 3
    Descriptor 1: POST memory resize
    Data Format 1: None
    Descriptor 2: POST error
    Data Format 2: POST results bitmap
    Descriptor 3: Log area reset/cleared
    Data Format 3: None

Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
    Number Of Devices: 2

Memory Device
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Samsung
    Serial Number: XXXXXXXX
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: M471B5173EB0-YK0  
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
    Minimum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.5 V
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Memory Device
    Total Width: Unknown
    Data Width: Unknown
    Size: No Module Installed
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: Unknown
    Type Detail: None
    Speed: Unknown
    Manufacturer: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: 9876543210
    Part Number: Not Specified
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: Unknown
    Minimum Voltage: Unknown
    Maximum Voltage: Unknown
    Configured Voltage: Unknown

Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Partition Width: 2

Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x000FFFFFFFF
    Range Size: 4 GB
    Partition Row Position: 254
    Interleave Position: 1
    Interleaved Data Depth: 1

Built-in Pointing Device
    Type: Touch Pad
    Interface: PS/2
    Buttons: 4

Portable Battery
    Location: Fake
    Manufacturer: -Virtual Battery 0-
    Manufacture Date: 08/08/2010
    Serial Number: Battery 0
    Name: CRB Battery 0
    Chemistry: Lithium Ion
    Design Capacity: Unknown
    Design Voltage: Unknown
    SBDS Version: Not Specified
    Maximum Error: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000

Hardware Security
    Power-On Password Status: Disabled
    Keyboard Password Status: Disabled
    Administrator Password Status: Disabled
    Front Panel Reset Status: Disabled

Voltage Probe
    Description: Voltage Probe Description
    Location: Unknown
    Status: Unknown
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00008000
    Nominal Value: 0.000 V

Cooling Device
    Type: Fan
    Status: OK
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00000000
    Nominal Speed: 8192 rpm
    Description: Cooling Device Description

Temperature Probe
    Description: Temperature Probe Description
    Location: Unknown
    Status: Unknown
    Maximum Value: Unknown
    Minimum Value: Unknown
    Resolution: Unknown
    Tolerance: Unknown
    Accuracy: Unknown
    OEM-specific Information: 0x00008000
    Nominal Value: 0.0 deg C

System Boot Information
    Status: No errors detected

System Power Supply
    Location: OEM Define 0
    Name: OEM Define 1
    Manufacturer: OEM Define 2
    Serial Number: OEM Define 3
    Asset Tag: OEM Define 4
    Model Part Number: OEM Define 5
    Revision: OEM Define 6
    Max Power Capacity: 75 W
    Status: Not Present
    Type: Regulator
    Input Voltage Range Switching: Auto-switch
    Plugged: No
    Hot Replaceable: No

Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: IGD
    Type: Video
    Status: Disabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a laptop of **Lenovo G-Series** with the same problem like you. As you can see, this laptop has been discontinued like mine. I've contacted Lenovo Support and all they have to say is that they don't offer support for these laptops anymore and that all I can do is check the documentation of it. As you understand, you'll never buy a laptop mentioning on the documentation that "Hey, I have a bug".

On my own research, I realised that the bug is **BIOS/UEFI firmware-related** and has nothing to do with Windows. I guess it will never be fixed, since the laptop has been discontinued. When it detects an external USB Mass Storage Media, it tries to add it to the correct boot order and messes up the boot order of the installed Operating Systems.

But don't worry! On [Rod Smith](https://askubuntu.com/a/962858/736783)'s post, you will see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/235802/736783) link, which is a good way to solve your problem. I've done something similar to my laptop.

Comment: Manufacturers completely stop working on discontinued products so I guess it will stay unpatched. Thank you for the details. Hope it works

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't an exact duplicate, but the following questions are related and are likely to hold an answer:

- [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager)
- [efibootmanager -o changes are lost on reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887210/efibootmanager-o-changes-are-lost-on-reboot)
- [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

You may also want to check my [page on boot coups.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) That page is part of my rEFInd documentation, but the principles apply to any boot loader, as do the solutions, albeit with minor tweaks to specific commands to change filenames, etc.

If the firmware is switching the boot order to Windows in response to your plugging in a USB drive, then that sounds like a firmware bug. As such, a firmware update may fix the problem; or you may need to report the bug to the manufacturer (and you'll probably never see a fix; manufacturers are bad about fixing that sort of bug).

Comment: It does not completely solve my question but you have some good tricks. Thank you for ur time!